# Angular Material Select close on backward tab

Tags: angular, angular-material, mat-select

I have a problem with closing `<mat-select>` when it is unfocused by backward tab.

When I am navigating on page with tabs after unfocusing select boxes are closing automaticly but if I am navigating with backward tab (shift + tab) it is not cloased.

Comment: Welcome to SO! Your question is not really clear to me. Do you have a reproducible code example? What is the desired behaviour, what is the actual behaviour?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.